# material-ui How change initial rowsPerPage in TablePagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Am new using material and i want to remove the select "Rows per page" and show 'n' rows, 10 for example.

```js
<TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
          component="div"
          count={rows.length}
          rowsPerPage={10}
          page={page}
          backIconButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "Previous Page"
          }}
          nextIconButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "Next Page"
          }}
          onChangePage={handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
```

[image]
But, the table continue showing 5 rows. How can I change this behavior? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working because it is a state and you are not changing it the right way, in this Material-UI example you have to initialize the value on the `React.useState()` as I did on the line 119 of [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/axtz6b) example.

```
const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(10); // this line will be the starting
```

Answer (score 8):

I tried the accepted answer however that requires more fine-grain control of how the individual rows are rendered.
If you just want to change the initial number of rows rendered, pass pageSize (seen here in the docs https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props) to the options property of MaterialTable like so

```
 <div>
      <MaterialTable
        icons={tableIcons}
        columns={props.column_mapper}
        data={props.data}
        title="Fancy Title Here"
        options={{
          search: true,
          exportButton: true,
          pageSize:10
        }}
      />
 </div>
```